# I have the following error in PHP using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, runtime-error, declare

I have the following error appearing using XAMPP *localhost*

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SN\includes\functions\session.php on line 146**

This error appears in the following code:

```
        /**
 * Session Start
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function session_start(){
    $session_id = '';

    if(SITE_USING_SSL){
        session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", TNB_DOMAIN, true, true);
    }else{
        session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", TNB_DOMAIN);
    }

    // Set Session Handler
    session_set_save_handler('_session_open', '_session_close', '_session_read', '_session_write', '_session_destroy', '_session_gc');

    // Change the default session name
    session_name(SESSION_NAME);

    // Check if session cookie is set and contains only letters and numbers
    if(isset($_COOKIE[SESSION_NAME])){
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_COOKIE[SESSION_NAME]) == false){
            $session_data = session_get_cookie_params();
            if(SITE_USING_SSL){
                setcookie(SESSION_NAME, null, time() - 42000, $session_data['path'], $session_data['domain'], true, true);
            }else{
                setcookie(SESSION_NAME, null, time() - 42000, $session_data['path'], $session_data['domain']);
            }
        }else{
            $session_id = $_COOKIE[SESSION_NAME];
        }
    }

    // If a session ID has been passed to the site, use it
    if(not_null($session_id)){
        session_id($session_id);
    }

    // Session Start
    if ($session_start_state != session_start()){
        $session_start_state = session_start();
    }

    // If not present, do not use the current session ID
    if(not_null($session_id)){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['session_start_time'])){
            session_recreate();
        }
    }

    // Server variable for new sessions. Recreate expired sessions.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['session_start_time'])){
        $_SESSION['session_start_time'] = time();
    }else{
        $curr_time = time();
        if($curr_time - $_SESSION['session_start_time'] > SESSION_LIFETIME){
            session_recreate();
            $_SESSION['session_start_time'] = time();
        }
    }

            //THIS IS LINE 146
return $session_start_state;
}
```

Do someone knows what's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your function so it doesn't clash with php predefined [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).